# Can I ask questions about vintage Apple products?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I'm troubleshooting some issues with an Apple IIc. Is it OK if I ask questions about my computer on Ask Different?

Comment: I would be so excited to see questions show up here about Apple II series products.

Answer (score 12):

All Apple products are on-topic here, but we also have a sister site in the network, [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), which specifically deals with questions about computer systems of yesteryear, including the [Apple II](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii).

Answer (score 7):

Sure, all Apple products are on-topic.