# Should I delete an accepted answer that's now very out of date?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Context: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35442/292

I agree with the comments left. The tool is no longer useful if you're on a modern macOS distribution.

Should I delete the answer? Leave it?

That it's an accepted answer that makes me hesitate to just delete it.

[Relevant meta discussion here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-should-we-manage-questions-that-have-very-different-answers-per-version-of-m) doesn't address what to do with accepted answers that fall out of date. Only what to do with questions.

Comment: See also this new Meta SE post: [Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370640/136010)

Comment: IMO you should edit it with a heading to clearly indicate that the answer works only on X version and previous.

Comment: Relevant MSE post: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/335251) It's worth noting (for the benefit of other users) that accepted answers can only be deleted by those with the "trusted user" privilege (granted at 20k reputation), as long as it's not your own answer - or by diamond mods.

Answer (score 11):

The question is explicitly about Lion. The answer is presumably still helpful for people using Lion. I would encourage you to leave it.

Comment: Leave it I shall!

Answer (score 4):

I’m tempted to mod lock the entire question / post as obsolete. Need to think over the options, but that seems the best way to handle an obsolete answer to a prominent post.

It was sure useful in the past but needs guard rails to protect people to make a new post or tread with caution using old information.

Comment: Possibly create a new question where the answer is rsync - or other current apps e.g. CCC and then close this as a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Old systems continue to exist in the world. If [we allow new questions about the Apple II](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/can-i-ask-questions-about-vintage-apple-products/3888#3888), we should also retain questions and answers about products such as Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Such questions and answers aren't actually obsolete as they are still historically relevant for the context in which they were asked.
If they provide potentially useful information, they are worth preserving.

But in cases where that isn't obvious, it would be good to add a disclaimer to the item, both as a warning that it no longer applies  to newer systems and to discourage anyone from posting "but nowadays one would …" answers.